# gorm automigrate not creating table

Tags: mysql, go, grails-orm

Building API in Golang. DB is connecting, but getting 500 errors on Postman requests. I think because the table I am trying to access is not being created in the migration.

Here is the error trace:

> Host: localhost:8080 Accept: */* Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
> Connection: keep-alive Content-Length: 103 Content-Type:
> application/json Postman-Token: 175ee0c2-e016-40e9-a599-ce0bce60a650
> User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.28.4
>
> runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
> /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:221 (0x1049c26)
> panicmem: panic(memoryError) /usr/local/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:735 (0x1049bf6)
> sigpanic: panicmem() /Users/dariusgoore/go/pkg/mod/github.com/jinzhu/gorm@v1.9.16/main.go:853
> (0x1309b9d)
> (*DB).clone: dialect:           newDialect(s.dialect.GetName(), s.db),
> /Users/dariusgoore/go/pkg/mod/github.com/jinzhu/gorm@v1.9.16/main.go:204
> (0x13036f0)
> (*DB).NewScope: dbClone := s.clone() /Users/dariusgoore/go/pkg/mod/github.com/jinzhu/gorm@v1.9.16/main.go:354
> (0x1305a4c)
> (*DB).Find: return s.NewScope(out).inlineCondition(where...).callCallbacks(s.parent.callbacks.queries).db
> /Users/dariusgoore/go/src/resource-api/Models/Client.go:11 (0x1504b77)
> GetAllClients: if err = Config.DB.Find(client).Error; err != nil { /Users/dariusgoore/go/src/resource-api/Controllers/Client.go:13
> (0x1504b7f)
> GetClients: err := Models.GetAllClients(&client) /Users/dariusgoore/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.7.4/context.go:165
> (0x14fbf01)
> (*Context).Next: c.handlersc.index /Users/dariusgoore/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.7.4/recovery.go:99
> (0x14fbeec)
> CustomRecoveryWithWriter.func1: c.Next() /Users/dariusgoore/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.7.4/context.go:165
> (0x14fb166)
> (*Context).Next: c.handlersc.index /Users/dariusgoore/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.7.4/logger.go:241
> (0x14fb149)
> LoggerWithConfig.func1: c.Next() /Users/dariusgoore/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.7.4/context.go:165
> (0x14fa69d)
> (*Context).Next: c.handlersc.index /Users/dariusgoore/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.7.4/gin.go:489
> (0x14fa325)
> (*Engine).handleHTTPRequest: c.Next() /Users/dariusgoore/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.7.4/gin.go:445
> (0x14f9e84)
> (*Engine).ServeHTTP: engine.handleHTTPRequest(c) /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2878 (0x1382b3a)
> serverHandler.ServeHTTP: handler.ServeHTTP(rw, req) /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1929 (0x137e1e7)
> (*conn).serve: serverHandler{c.server}.ServeHTTP(w, w.req) /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1581 (0x10645a0)
> goexit: BYTE    $0x90   // NOP

Here is Controllers/Client.go:

```
package Controllers

import (
    "resource-api/Models"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

//GetClients ... Get all clients
func GetClients(c *gin.Context) {
    var client []Models.Client
    err := Models.GetAllClients(&client)
    if err != nil {
        c.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusNotFound)
    } else {
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, client)
    }
} ...
```

And Models/Client.go

```
package Models

import (
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "resource-api/Config"
)

//GetAllClients Fetch all client data
func GetAllClients(client *[]Client) (err error) {
    if err = Config.DB.Find(client).Error; err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
...
```

And Models/ClientModel.go:

```
package Models

type Client struct {
    Id           uint      `json:"id"`
    Name        string    `json:"name"`
    URL       string    `json:"url"`
    Description  string    `json:"description"`
}
func (c *Client) TableName() string {
    return "client"
}
```

And main.go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gorm.io/driver/mysql"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "resource-api/Config"

    "resource-api/Models"
    "resource-api/Routes"
)

var err error

func main() {

    db, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(Config.DbURL(Config.BuildDBConfig())), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Status:", err)
    }
    defer Config.DB.Close()


    db.Debug().AutoMigrate(&Models.Client{})
    r := Routes.SetupRouter()
    //running
    r.Run()
}
```

Adding Config/Database.go in response to comments:

```
package Config

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
)

var DB *gorm.DB

// DBConfig represents db configuration
type DBConfig struct {
    Host string
    Port int
    User string
    DBName string
    Password string
}

func BuildDBConfig() *DBConfig {
    dbConfig := DBConfig{
        Host: "localhost",
        Port: 3306,
        User: "root",
        Password: "654321cg",
        DBName: "resourcesdb",
    }
    return &dbConfig
}

func DbURL(dbConfig *DBConfig) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf(
        "%s:%s@tcp(%s:%d)/%s?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local",
        dbConfig.User,
        dbConfig.Password,
        dbConfig.Host,
        dbConfig.Port,
        dbConfig.DBName,
        )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the config file. It would be much easier to debug the point of failure. After going through your screenshots I can see you have created connection in `main.go` file. Nice and you have also migrated the db but in your `Models/Client.go` file you are accessing a pointer variable which should be the db connection object you created in your `main.go` file and I don't think you are using that db connection object.

Comment: Added config file to the question.

Comment: ok so you are accessing the DB object from the Config file to query data but you didn't assign your db connection object from main.go file to this config's DB object. That's why you are getting nil pointer error.

Comment: so this line is incorrect?: `db, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(Config.DbURL(Config.BuildDBConfig())), &gorm.Config{})`

Comment: nope I didn't say that. I said you need to use this db object to query from your db. But you are using this `DB` from config object which is not even initialised and by default it's nil in golang. For now to make your code work add this line `Config.DB = db` after this line `db, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(Config.DbURL(Config.BuildDBConfig())), &gorm.Config{})`

Comment: tried that and changed package in Database.go from "github.com/jinzhu/gorm" to "gorm.io/gorm". got a new error. Postman returns 404, but in terminal I get ` /...../Models/Client.go:11 dial tcp [::1]:3306: connect: connection refused
[0.943ms] [rows:0] SELECT * FROM `client`
[GIN] 2021/08/29 - 07:32:42 | 404 |    1.005165ms |             ::1 | GET      "/clients/client"`

Comment: make sure your mysql is running!